# How to keep UTF8 encoding during xml parse, attribute value change and file writing? (python)

Tags: python, utf-8, type-conversion, googletrans

I'm writing a programm in Python, my goal is to :

- read input xml file one line at a time
- for each line find "CH" attribute
- change attribute value : translate from french to portugese
- write changed line into output xml file
- as i manipulate texts in various languages i'd like to keep utf8 encoding to display foreign special characters in the output file

My code:

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from googletrans import Translator



        with open("input file.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as input_file:
            with open("output file.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
                # Read input file
                for ligne in input_file:
                        # line parse
                        root = ET.fromstring(ligne)

                        # Change CH attribute value, translate from french fr to portugese pt
                        current_text= root.get("CH")
                        translator = Translator()
                        translated_text = translator.translate(dest="pt", src="fr", text=current_text)
                        root.attrib["CH"] = translated_text.text

                        # convert bytes to string 
                        decoded_string = ET.tostring(root).decode("utf-8")
                        
                        # write output file
                        output_file.write(decoded_string)
```

The problem is that in the output file i get non encoded chraracters, for example with the below input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SCRIBUSUTF8NEW Version="1.5.5">
        <StoryText>
                <DefaultStyle ALIGN="1" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0"/>
                <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Bold" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="la victoire est à nous"/>
                <para ALIGN="1" LINESP="10"/>
                <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Bold" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="vive l'empereur"/>
                <trail ALIGN="1" LINESP="10"/>
        </StoryText>
</SCRIBUSUTF8NEW>
```

i get this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SCRIBUSUTF8NEW Version="1.5.5">
        <StoryText>
                <DefaultStyle ALIGN="1" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0"/>
                <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Bold" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="A vit&#243;ria &#233; nossa" />                                          
                <para ALIGN="1" LINESP="10"/>
                <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Bold" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="Vida longa ao" />                 
                <trail ALIGN="1" LINESP="10"/>
        </StoryText>
</SCRIBUSUTF8NEW>
```

instead of expected result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SCRIBUSUTF8NEW Version="1.5.5">
        <StoryText>
                <DefaultStyle ALIGN="1" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0"/>
                <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Bold" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="A vitória é nossa" /> 
                <para ALIGN="1" LINESP="10"/>
                <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Bold" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="Vida longa ao" />                 
                <trail ALIGN="1" LINESP="10"/>
        </StoryText>
</SCRIBUSUTF8NEW>
```

i have checked with displays that the translated_text.text is well formated ("A vitória é nossa"), but decoded_string value is wrong despite utf8 coding specification : `<ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Bold" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="A vit&#243;ria &#233; nossa" />`

i do not understand why i have this result, could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Parse the whole tree and iterate the ITEXT nodes.  The following demonstrates how to change and write the text.  Write the modified tree with the `.write()` method using an XML declaration and declaring the encoding:

```py
# pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
# Note 3.0.0 didn't work
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import googletrans as gt

tree = ET.parse('input file.txt')
translator = gt.Translator()
for itext in tree.iterfind('*/ITEXT'):
    current_text = itext.get('CH')
    itext.attrib['CH'] = translator.translate(dest="pt", src="fr", text=current_text).text
tree.write('output file.txt', xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

**output file.txt**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SCRIBUSUTF8NEW Version="1.5.5">
        <StoryText>
                <DefaultStyle ALIGN="1" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" />
                <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Bold" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="A vitória é nossa" />
                <para ALIGN="1" LINESP="10" />
                <ITEXT FONT="Times New Roman Bold" SCALEH="100" SCALEV="100" BASEO="0" KERN="0" CH="Vida longa ao" />
                <trail ALIGN="1" LINESP="10" />
        </StoryText>
</SCRIBUSUTF8NEW>
```